# Getting Run-time error '3346': number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderDetails ([Supplier], [Item], [Quantity], [Cost/EA], [Total]) SELECT(" & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Supplier]" & "." & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Item]" & "." & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Quantity]" & "." & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Cost/EA]" & "." & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Total]" & ");"

    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

End Sub
```

Comment: I have, but have not been able to narrow down what is driving the error as I have checked values and destination fields, and all seem to match up.

Comment: Use your debugger. At the line DoCmd.RunSQL, copy the strSQL value and that should help you find problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` statement you are assembling there is using a period to separate the columns.  Try using a comma.

From:

```
& "." & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Item]" & "."
```

To:

```
& "," & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Item]" & ","
```

Complete:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO PurchaseOrderDetails ([Supplier], [Item], [Quantity], [Cost/EA], [Total]) SELECT(" & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Supplier]" & "," & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Item]" & ", " & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Quantity]" & "," & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Cost/EA]" & "," & "Me.OrderSelection_subform![Total]" & ");"    
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
```

Comment: I changed the periods to commas as suggested, and also changed SELECT to VALUES, and now it is asking me to enter parameter values.  How do I have it select the values in the subform?

Comment: Can you show what strSQL is at runtime?  Also, it would helpful to indicate what database platform you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from subfrom must be `[forms]![NameofParentForm]![Form].[SubFormname].[ControlName]`

Sample:

```
docmd.Runsql "Insert into TableName([FieldName]) values([forms]![NameofParentForm]![Form].[SubFormName].[ControlName])"
```